# POST to a .JSON static file in MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been developing a web project and using `.json` files to retrieve data via `$.ajax` calls on the client.  Those calls all use POST, because parameters will be passed, etc.
When I put the .json files in the application, I receive a 405 error, complaining that I cannot POST to that file.  I assume it wants me to use GET, but I want to use POST so that I don't have to change the way those methods are written when we move them to Controller Action calls, or Web Api, etc.

How can I allow a POST to a static .json file in an MVC project?

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Not putting this as an answer as it doesn't answer your question but as a workaround, why not simply make stub controller actions & return the data in the flat file? That way you don't need to change anything when you switch to controller code.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau, that's likely what we'll do, but it would be nice to hit those directly!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can not POST to those files is because you don't have any handlers (PHP, ASPNET, etc) associated with `.json` files that can handle the `POST` verb.

A really easy work-around is to make a `JsonController` controller with actions corresponding to your views..

VB - you can translate

```
<ActionName("AJsonFile.json")>
Public Function AJsonFile As JsonResult
  ' Return the .json file content
End Function
```

That way you can keep your views as `.cshtml` files, which are registered with the asp net processor, and not have to worry about mapping a new file type.